# Obtener valores de un button con ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

¿Como puedo hacer para obtener los valores de un botón con ajax?
Verán, trato de hacer un código dónde mediante ajax estoy haciendo una consulta asíncrona de una vista a un archivo php, la cuestión está en que yo en mi archivo php estoy enviando unos elementos `<tr>` con su debido `<button>` de eliminar con el valor de los datos que quiero eliminar, la cosa está en que cuando hago un evento click en jQuery si me atrae el valor pero del `<tbody>` y no puedo acceder al valor del `<button>` con la función de jQuery `.child()`.

Adjunto códigos.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body onload="funcionBuscar()">
        <table >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope='col'>Nombre de usuario</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Correo electrónico</th>
                    <th scope='col'></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tabla" value="Lo que salga aquí">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="procesar.js"></script>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(funcionprincipal);


function funcionprincipal(){
    $('#tabla').click('.btn',funcionBorrar);
}

function funcionBuscar(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'procesar.php',
        dataType: 'html'
    }).done(
        function(data){
            $('#tabla').html(data);
        }
    );
}

function funcionBorrar(){
    alert( $(this).child('tr').child('tr').attr('value') );
}
```

Nótese que en la funcionBorrar estoy mandado un alert con el supuesto valor del button, mas no sale absolutamente nada, si elimino los `.child()` y solo dejo el `$(this).attr('value')` me mostrará solo el valor del `tbody`.

php

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "prueba") or die ('no se pudo');
    $tabla = "";
    $Consulta = "SELECT USUARIO, CORREO FROM CUENTAS";
    $Query = mysqli_query($conexion, $Consulta);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Query)){
        $tabla.="
        <tr class='tr'>
            <td>$rows[USUARIO]</td>
            <td>$rows[CORREO]</td>
            <td class='td'><button value='$rows[USUARIO]' class='btn'>Eliminar</button></td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
    echo $tabla;
?>
```

SQL

```
CREATE DATABASE PRUEBA;
CREATE TABLE CUENTAS(
    USUARIOS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CORREO VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONTRASENIA VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Les agradecería si me pudieran apoyar, Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu funcionprincipal() debería ser:

```
function funcionprincipal() {
  $("#tabla").on('click', ".btn", funcionBorrar);
}
```

Y tu funcionBorrar debería ser:

```
function funcionBorrar() {
  alert($(this).attr("value"));
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me funcionó perfectamente. Saludos. :)